# Unable to import ParseImageView,ParseQueryAdapter for sdk versoin 1.13.0

Tags: android

I tried importing `com.parse.ParseImageView` and `com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter`  using the code below.  But it shows this error:

`Error:(26, 13) 
Failed to resolve: com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1
Error:(27, 13) 
Failed to resolve: com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1`

```
package com.example.satti.party;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseImageView;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;




public class customadp extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

public customadp(Context context) {
    // Use the QueryFactory to construct a PQA that will only show
    // Todos marked as high-pri
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("city");
            query.whereEqualTo("highPri", true);
            return query;
        }
    });
}

// Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.actvity_priest1, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    // Add and download the image
    ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("image");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
        todoImage.loadInBackground();
    }

    // Add the title view
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("title"));

    // Add a reminder of how long this item has been outstanding
    TextView timestampView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cur);
    timestampView.setText(object.getCreatedAt().toString());
    return v;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add at you gradle build file under the dependencies tag :

```
compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1',
compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1'
```

Comment: I added  those two lines in  my gradle but it  showing the errorsError:(26, 13) 
Failed to resolve: com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1
Error:(27, 13) 
Failed to resolve: com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This sequence *in this order* in gradle worked for me

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1'
```